# ListView.BackColor not working for current row, after next search item it works

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listitem

I have a weird issue. I'm using ListView item in VB.NET Forms. During my search for partial text (SearchText can be abc), when found for the first instance I try to change the BackColor for a list item it's not changing the BackColor for the current row.

Whereas when I search for a new matched item it shows previous searched item BackColor as blue. Any suggestion to resolve the issue? My goal is to color the current matched row.

```
Public Function SearchGridFindNext(ByRef Grid As ListView, ByVal SearchText As String, Optional ByVal FromBeginning As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    Dim StartRowIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim StartNextRowIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim RowIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim IncrementIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim Found As Boolean = False

    If Grid.Items.Count > 0 Then
        If Grid.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            StartRowIndex = Grid.SelectedItems(0).Index
            If FromBeginning Then StartNextRowIndex = 0 Else StartNextRowIndex = Grid.SelectedItems(0).Index + 1
            Grid.SelectedItems.Clear()
        End If

        For RowIndex = StartRowIndex To Grid.Items.Count - 1
            If RowIndex > StartRowIndex Then
                StartNextRowIndex = 0
            End If
            For IncrementIndex = 1 To StartNextRowIndex - 1
                Grid.Items(IncrementIndex).BackColor = Color.White
            Next
            For IncrementIndex = StartNextRowIndex To Grid.Items.Count - 1
                If (Grid.Items(IncrementIndex).SubItems(0).Text.ToUpper.Contains(SearchText)) Then
                    Grid.Items(IncrementIndex).Selected = True
                    Grid.Items(IncrementIndex).EnsureVisible()
                    Grid.Items(IncrementIndex).BackColor = Color.Blue
                    Found = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If Found Then Exit For
        Next
    End If
    Return Found
End Function
```

Comment: SubItems would indicate a ListView, not a ListBox.

Comment: That's true.
Public Function SearchGridFindNext(ByRef Grid As ListView, ByVal SearchText As String, Optional ByVal FromBeginning As Boolean = False) As Boolean

Comment: Why are you declaring that `Grid` parameter `ByRef`?  It's a reference type and you're not assigning anything to it inside the method so there's no reason for it.  VB.NET is not VB6.  Reference types don't get copied when you pass them to methods.  `ByVal` means passing the value of a variable and the value of a reference type variable is already a reference.

Comment: I added full code and it works to search the text within ListView Items. The problem I have is with BackColor not working hence I'm requesting for direction (when I click on search again, the same function will be called with same SearchText, BackColor works for previously searched item but not current. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: You don't need to repeat what you have already posted in your question.  I can read.  The fact that the code you have achieves your end goal doesn't mean that declaring a parameter `ByRef` when it should be `ByVal` is good programming.  If you want to write good code then take advice about writing good code when it's provided, whether it addresses the specific question you're asking or not.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I understand what you mentioned, I’ll focus on changing ByRef, however my goal at the moment is not that, functionality works but BackColor is not working, that’s my attention at the moment if you can answer.

Comment: I don't really understand your algorithm.  It seems rather convoluted and, with no comments, hard to understand.  It's hard to test reproducing an issue if you don't understand what the code is actually doing.  If that convoluted algorithm isn't actually relevant then you probably shouldn't have posted it.  You should post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem, i.e. everything we need and nothing we don't.  Other code that just muddies the waters makes providing an answer more difficult.

Comment: There is a search box, when we enter partial characters and click on a button, I’m calling the function, there is a ListView items to search, it highlights first row when found with match, next time when I hit the button again with same search text, it highlights the next match. The code does it with loop. Hope that helps, I’m trying to change the background color as default highlighted color is too light.